# How to use Filter and Servlet in different packages?

Tags: java, servlets, filter, servlet-filters, eclipse-jee

I have a servlet, a filter and a login.jsp. I fill the username and pasword and then click the login button and the filter isn't called, only the servlet is called. The servlet and filter are in different packages and I see this is the problem. If I put servlet and filter in the same package the filter is called successfully. But I want to use them in different packages. What should I do? Thanks in advance!

[image]

Filter:

```
package log.reg.myfilter;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

@WebFilter("/LoginFilter")
public class LoginFilter implements Filter {

    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) 
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 

        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request; 
        String username = req.getParameter("username"); 
        String pass = req.getParameter("password1"); 

        System.out.println(username); 

        if ((username.length() > 6) && (pass.length() > 3)) {

            System.out.println("In filter");  
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
        else
            out.println("Invalid Input");
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

Servlet:

```
package log.reg;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/firstServlet")
public class FirstServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        System.out.println("In servlet");

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        String username = request.getParameter("username"); 
        out.println("Welcome " + username); 
    }

}
```

login.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="firstServlet" method="get">
        <table style="background-color: lightgreen; margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 20px">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <h3 style="color: red">Login Page!!!</h3>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>UserName : </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="username"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password : </td>
                <td><input type="password" name="password1"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="login"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>Servlet ex29 - filter</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `value()` of `@WebServlet` and `@WebFilter` don't have the same meaning.
The first one specifies the URL patterns of the servlet (that is its URL mapping) while the second one specifies the URL patterns **to which the filter applies**.

But in both cases you specified as name the simple name of the underlying class.
For the servlet, `@WebServlet("/firstServlet")` makes sense but annotating your `Filter` with `@WebFilter("/LoginFilter")` is not what you are looking for as 
you don't want to filter only the `"/LoginFilter"` URL.

For example to filter any requested URL you could specify :
`@WebFilter("/*")`

Comment: Thanks for reply! I want to add more servlets and jsp pages. What should I do if I want to filter all the servlets and jsp except login.jsp?

Comment: You are welcome. You could put all protected resources (jsp) and all protected servlet mappings in a specific base path , for example `/private`. Then  apply the filter on this path such as `@WebFilter("/private/*")`.  And to allow the login to be accessible, place it at a place not considered by the filter such as the root of the context : "/".

Comment: And how can I make this /private base path? In web.xml or where can I do it?

Comment: In the mapping for the servlets such as `@WebServlet("/private/firstServlet")` and move your private static resources in  the `WEB-INF/private` folder.

Answer (score 0):

A Servlet filter is an object that can intercept HTTP requests targeted at your web application. As I see here, you have not associated filter with servlet. You have to tell the url pattern you want to intercept/filter.

> Note: Filter won't be executed independently it works with
>   Servlet. So You have to associated Filter with Servlets.

If you have to associate with FirstServlet then use below one.

```
  @WebFilter("/firstServlet")
```

If you want to filter each request you can use `/*`

```
  @WebFilter("/*")
```